# Reporting services 2016 (ssrs) prompts with username/password

Tags: ssrs-2016

[Authentications Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj9z2.png)

When I open SQL Reporting Services 2016 it's prompt above windows authentications. I need to bypass prompt and allow direct login to service.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the datasource to something specific, rather than the default?

Check the settings below, and depending how you access the database (SQL Auth or Windows Auth) You'll need to set the values accordingly.

[image]